# I am having problem will installing development

Tags: permissions, kali-linux, mono, fat, updatedb

I am nod able to install mono development even after i gave `apt get update`. My system is asking for

```
Mono depends on =6.10.0.104-0-xamarin16+debian10b1
```

Its also asking

Hit https://download.mono-project.com/rep/debian vs-buster Inrelease

Answer (score 2):

Several things spring to mind. Here are three

1. Don't install packages from repositories [other than Kali's own](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/). At best you'll end up with package version mismatches, and worst you'll break your system.

   Here's what Kali's authors have to say on the subject (my emphasis),

   > *adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), **will break your installation**. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break.​If any guides are telling you to do anything else than the above, this is unofficial advice, and completely not supported by Kali Linux. More often than not, users in this case end up doing a reinstall after learning this lesson.​​​*
2. Don't use Kali as a daily driver, but instead [keep it for security and penetration testing](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/). It has all sorts of strange corners specificially because it's designed for security testing

   Here's what Kali documentation says,

   > *Kali Linux is specifically geared to meet the requirements of professional penetration testing and security auditing. To achieve this, several core changes have been implemented in Kali Linux which reflect these needs*
3. Get yourself a well-supported general purpose distribution (Mint, Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora, etc.) and use that for your development work. You could even run Kali as a VM on this system should you need to do so - but be aware that all of Kali's applications are already freely available on other distributions.